# The service return status code 200 but not return data

Tags: android, rest, .net-core, service, webapi

I made some rest services by `.ne`t core *API*. I called them in the Android application with the below code. Sometimes the service worked and returned data but sometimes I get `status code 200` but not return any value. I am confused! I don't know what happened and why the specific method sometimes works and sometimes not works!

The service:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PMServicesController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IPMServices pmService;

    public PMServicesController(
        IPMServices pmService)
    {
        this.pmService = pmService;
    }
    [Route("Test"), HttpPost]
    public string set(string test)
    {
        return "Test is successfull";
    }
}
```

In android:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    try {

        String uri = serviceURL + "/" + methodName;

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                connectionTimeout);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, socketTimeOut);
        httpClient.setParams(httpParameters);
        HttpResponse response = null;

        this.requestType = HttpRequestType.GET;
        if (params.length == 1) {
            this.requestType = HttpRequestType.POST;
        }
        /*if (params.length > 1)
            if (params[0] != null)
                this.requestType = HttpRequestType.POST;*/


        if (this.requestType == HttpRequestType.POST) {
            // /// Input parameter exists /////////////

            //this.jsonStringer = getJsonStringFromObject(params);
            this.jsonStringer=params[0].toString();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            StringEntity msg = new StringEntity(jsonStringer,HTTP.UTF_8);
            msg.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                    "application/json"));
            msg.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                    "application/json"));


            request.setEntity(msg);
            response = httpClient.execute(request);
        } else {
            uri = uri ;//+ "?" + params[0];
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
            response = httpClient.execute(request);
        }

        /*int b;
        if(methodName.equalsIgnoreCase("PostCurrent"))
           b = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();*/
        int r = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        isCommunicationSucceed = r == 200;
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
        // Read response data into buffer
        int contentLength = (int) responseEntity.getContentLength();
        String result = "";
        // if (r == 200) {
        if (contentLength > 0) {
            char[] buffer = new char[contentLength];
            InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            int hasRead = 0;
            int readsize = 0;
            while (hasRead < contentLength) {
                readsize = reader.read(buffer, hasRead, contentLength
                        - hasRead);
                //
                publishProgress((readsize * 100) / contentLength);
                //
                if (readsize == -1)
                    break;
                hasRead += readsize;
            }
            // reader.read(buffer);
            stream.close();
            result = new String(buffer).toString().trim();
        } else {
            if (AppConstant.DEBUG_MODE)
                Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "Empty Result in WebService: "
                        + serviceURL + "/" + methodName);
        }
      return result;
}
```

Comment: Do not use HttpClient anymore. It's long deprecated.

Comment: How to call this with Retrofit?

Answer (score 0):

Is your API working fine with a postman or fiddler call ?

Server side, you could try :

```
public ActionResult<string> set(string test)
{
    return Ok("Test is successfull");
}
```

or async version

```
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> set(string test)
    {
        return Ok("Test is successfull");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes it works good with postman and sometimes works in Android app and return data but more times it doesn't send any data and sent status code 200

Comment: Ok, did you try async in web api Method ?

Comment: I changed my method but again I get status code 200 and data is empty

Comment: So It is client side issue.i know less about android, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

use retrofit instead of HttpClient.

add to build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
```

add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

use online tool to make javaObject from your json response

```
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
```

make interface for retrofit for example:

```
public interface MyInterface {

    @GET("posts")
    Call<List<Post>> getPosts();

}
```

make instance of retrofit

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("YOUR_API")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

use your interface and retrofit to make simple GET http request

```
MyInterface myInterface = retrofit.create(MyInterface.class);

 Call<List<Post>> listCall = MyInterface.getPosts();
```

then

```
listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    //doSomething
                    return;
                }

                //do something with your response

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
              //do something
            }
        });

    }
```